# Braintree IOS + rails error 91564 Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

I'm getting an error from Braintree on Braintree::Transaction.sale

```
Braintree::ErrorResult params:{...} errors:transaction:[(91564)
  Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once.
```

However when I check the nonce token, it's always different from the last request.

Sample nonces received from IOS app:

```
10e368f1-81bc-4ace-b4b4-76cfdc4d1459
02cc81b2-d6c7-416b-b5d5-5b23c7e81fad
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. Without seeing your code, both iOS and Ruby, we can't tell you where the problem is. I suggest you [email our support team with details](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) when you have Braintree-specific problems.

Comment: got the issue resolved.. I was trying to do add cards manually through paymentMethod.create  using a nonce... same nonce i was using for Transaction.Sale instead of using the token there...

Comment: Thanks for looking in to the issue...

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You can always post your own answer and accept it when you figure out your own problem.

Comment: hi all can any once give suggestions and help for paypal integration for android.when am integrating paypal from braintree for drop in ui option with paypal and creditcard if am working with creditcard option gfetting success response.come with paypal redirecting to browser view for paypal sandbox account login page after giving creditials agree and pay getting error:Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once please help how can i solve in onRequestActivity for calling checkout api please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got the issue resolved.. I was trying to do add cards manually through paymentMethod.create using a nonce... same nonce i was using for Transaction.Sale instead of using the token returned by PaymentMethod.create.

Comment: Rule of thumb: 1st request use paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient, subsequent calls use paymentMethodToken: token

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add

```
$('#js-payment-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

to make the following configuration work

```
braintree.setup("clienttoken", "custom", {
    id: 'js-payment-form',
    paypal: {
        container: "paypal-button",
        displayName: "Test"
    }
});
```